# How to max one column than max another column to avoid repeated combinations SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ID1 | Date1 | 5 |
| ID1 | Date2 | 5 |
| ID2 | Date3 | 4 |
| ID2 | Date4 | 4 |
| ID3 | Date5 | 5 |
| ID4 | Date6 | 6 |
| ID5 | Date7 | 2 |
| ID6 | Date8 | 2 |

a is an ID (String)
b is a date
c is a string
d is an int

This is the SQL query I am using

```
select S."a","b","c" from
    (select max("d"), "a"
    from public."x"
    group by "a") F
    join "x" S on F."max" = S."d"
    and S."a" = F."a"
    LIMIT 10;
```

How do I only keep unique pairings of a and c in my table. Such that the row that is kept is the pairing with the later b value (later date)? For example, if Date1 in the table was later than date2 in the table, I would only want to include the ID1/C combo containing Date1 rather than also including the ID1/C combo containing Date2.

I'm new to Sql thank you for your patience!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select a,c,max(b) from 
(<your query>) as Q
group by a,c
```

Assuming  above has a limit of 10 to keep it simple.  You'll just get grouping on some random 10 if you keep it there with no order by.

If you really want 10 you need to move the TOP outside the inner query *and add an `ORDER BY`* so it picks a useful 10.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @LoztInSpace. I am new to SQL so I'm sorry if I am not understanding this correctly. What you mean by <your query> is the entire query that I have above? So I would essentially have 3 select statements? Also, by TOP, do you mean that I should move the limit 10 outside the inner query to the one that you have wrote? Thanks again for the quick answer!

Comment: Yes, put whatever your query is inside the <your query here>.  I phrased it like this a) so you can more easily see what's going on and also b) because I don't know if you can simplify the inner query but what I have given you is the general pattern for values with a maximum (and/or minimum) of that group.  Regarding top 10 - it depends on what your requirement is but as it stands it will be top 10 at random (because it's  not sorted) of the inner query.  That might not be what you want as top 10 there might result in only 1 record if they've got the same `a`.